# Calculate efficiently an expensive hermitian matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, coding-style

I want to compute a matrix $M_{pq}$, for which the calculation of each coefficients $M_{pq} = f(p,q)$ is an expensive function. I know that my matrix is hermitian, so that $M_{qp} = M_{pq}^{*}$. As a consequence, I only need to compute roughly one half of the matrix coefficients to determine entirely the matrix $M$. Once I performed the expensive calculation of determining the list

```
halfM = Table[f[p,q],{p,1,n},{q,p,n}];
```

I then have all the information needed to reconstruct the full matrix $M$.

My question is then :

How would you then build-up the matrix $M$ ensuring that no other calculations are performed ? What could be the best way to operate on the lists in order to construct $M$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pad missed elements and add a transposed matrix

```
M = # + ConjugateTranspose@UpperTriangularize[#, 1] &@PadLeft@halfM;

M // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was doable, but didn't know `PadLeft`. I am also always really impressed by the shortened syntax you used, which is not yet in my reach

Comment: @jibe In that case, [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) should be a useful starting point.